# updated to 14.04 on netbook, super slow, not working with monitor

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-netbook

This is my first post, to be honest I'm not very experienced with this. My uncle usually helps but I can't reach him so... I'm needing some help. 
At the moment my velocity micro m10 netbook is my only computer. I updated my ubuntu netbook remix to 14.04 because I was promoted to. 
Net books are crazy small so I set mine up to my Dell monitor and have a wireless mouse and keyboard hooked up.
once everything downloaded I got to the login screen, everything looked great on the netbook but on the monitor it was like a broken up background picture (tough to explain)
I get logged in and both the monitor and netbook screen look great but I try to move the mouse and it shows up on only one screen. I try to open the home button and it's super slow and choppy to opening windows.the Internet is slow to pop up but fast like usual once it gets going. It seems like just the OS is slow. I tried checking the Nvidia drivers and I guess I've got 304. I tried following some of what these forums say to do in the terminal but the terminal told me horrible things will happen if I proceed (it literally told me that).
my question is how can I fix this slowness? And how come I cannot get the monitor to display what is on my netbook screen since I did the update?

Can anyone help with this strange issue or tell me how to wipe it out and try to download it again... i feel like something must have gone wrong with the update

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with Unity which requires more power for effects, usability etc. My suggestion is install other desktop enviroment like XFCE.

Install XFCE desktop from terminal with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` then logout. On login screen, change Unity enviroment to XFCE by clicking Ubuntu logo righ after